# Search and replace a pathname in Linux using sed

Tags: shell-script, sed

I'm trying to replace a pathname in a shell script. I've looked at dozens of examples concerning this, but to no avail.

I want to replace `"/home/imp"` with `"/home/rg"`

Thanks.

Comment: why sed? why not just use mv or rename ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/\/home\/imp/\/home\/rg/g' filename
```

use `sed -i` to edit file in place

Answer (score 2):

try

```
sed -i s:/home/imp:/home/rg:g filename
```

- no need to quote if no special character
- `-i` tell sed to edit in place
- delimiter can be any char, I choose `:` to avoid backslahing `/`
- `s` is for substitue
- `g` is for global (multiple substitute per line)